# Bspwm session displays only grey screen and keybindings dont work

Tags: window-manager, bspwm, sxhkd

Here are my bspwmrc and sxhkdrc files

```
#AUTOSTART
picom --config ~/.config/picom/picom.conf
nitrogen --restore &
$HOME/.config/polybar/launch.sh
pgrep -x sxhkd > /dev/null || sxhkd &
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr &

bspc monitor -d "I" "II" "III" "IV" "V"

wm-restack = bspwm

bspc config border_width    0
bspc config window_gap      25

bspc config split_ratio     0.52
bspc config borderless_monocle  true
bspc config gapless_monocle true
bspc config focus_follows_pointer true

bspc rule -a Gimp desktop='^8' state=floating follow=on
bspc rule -a Chromium desktop='^2'
bspc rule -a mplayer2 state=floating
bspc rule -a kupfer.py focus=on
bspc rule -a Screenkey manage=off
```

---

```
#
# wm independent hotkeys
#

# terminal emulator
super + Return
    alacritty

# program launcher
super + p
    dmenu_run

# make sxhkd reload its configuration files:
super + Escape
    pkill -USR1 -x sxhkd

#
# bspwm hotkeys
#

# quit/restart bspwm
super + alt + {q,r}
    bspc {quit,wm -r}

# close and kill
super + {_,shift + }w
    bspc node -{c,k}

# alternate between the tiled and monocle layout
super + m
    bspc desktop -l next

# send the newest marked node to the newest preselected node
super + y
    bspc node newest.marked.local -n newest.!automatic.local

# swap the current node and the biggest window
super + g
    bspc node -s biggest.window

#
# state/flags
#

# set the window state
super + {t,shift + t,s,f}
    bspc node -t {tiled,pseudo_tiled,floating,fullscreen}

# set the node flags
super + ctrl + {m,x,y,z}
    bspc node -g {marked,locked,sticky,private}

#
# focus/swap
#

# focus the node in the given direction
super + {_,shift + }{h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -{f,s} {west,south,north,east}

# focus the node for the given path jump
super + {p,b,comma,period}
    bspc node -f @{parent,brother,first,second}

# focus the next/previous window in the current desktop
super + {_,shift + }c
    bspc node -f {next,prev}.local.!hidden.window

# focus the next/previous desktop in the current monitor
super + bracket{left,right}
    bspc desktop -f {prev,next}.local

# focus the last node/desktop
super + {grave,Tab}
    bspc {node,desktop} -f last

# focus the older or newer node in the focus history
super + {o,i}
    bspc wm -h off; \
    bspc node {older,newer} -f; \
    bspc wm -h on

# focus or send to the given desktop
super + {_,shift + }{1-9,0}
    bspc {desktop -f,node -d} '^{1-9,10}'

#
# preselect
#

# preselect the direction
super + ctrl + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -p {west,south,north,east}

# preselect the ratio
super + ctrl + {1-9}
    bspc node -o 0.{1-9}

# cancel the preselection for the focused node
super + ctrl + space
    bspc node -p cancel

# cancel the preselection for the focused desktop
super + ctrl + shift + space
    bspc query -N -d | xargs -I id -n 1 bspc node id -p cancel

#
# move/resize
#

# expand a window by moving one of its side outward
super + alt + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -z {left -20 0,bottom 0 20,top 0 -20,right 20 0}

# contract a window by moving one of its side inward
super + alt + shift + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -z {right -20 0,top 0 20,bottom 0 -20,left 20 0}

# move a floating window
super + {Left,Down,Up,Right}
    bspc node -v {-20 0,0 20,0 -20,20 0}
```

When i log in with gnome my window manager works fine so i think the problem is with bspwm because after logging into a bspwm session the only thing i can see is a grey screen with no errors or no cursor response whatsoever. The keybindings i set in sxhkdrc also do not seem to work either.

Comment: You probably just need to start picom in the background: `picom --config ~/.config/picom/picom.conf &` or it'll block. (Maybe the polybar script too depending on how it's written...)

Comment: Also if it's a bash variable, you probably need to remove the spaces in `wm-restack = bspwm` (though I'm not sure what that does here... that maybe belongs in your polybar config?) : `wm-restack=bspwm`, and add a shebang to the script.